# Оператор this для чего это , это необходимо?

Tags: c++

```
Prostokat & Prostokat::operator++(int)
 {
this->bok1 *=2;
 this->bok2 *=2;
 this->Pole();
 this->Obwod();
 return *this;
 }
```

Что это this? Это необходимо?

Comment: this это указатель на объект класса. Именно с помощью него можно получать доступ к переменным и методам класса, хотя обычно достаточно к ним можно обращаться без указания this (синтаксический сахар). Однако чтобы вернуть ссылку на текущий объект кроме как обратиться к this способа нет

Comment: не забудьте поставить галочку!

Answer (score 2):

Как сказали в комментариях, this - указатель на объект класса.
Он очень полезен при присваивании значений параметров конструктора полям внутри класса, если поле и параметр имеют одинаковое имя, например:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    int field;

    MyClass(int field)
    {
        this->field = field; //Присвоили значение параметра полю класса, все ОК
        field = field; /*Здесь компилятор подумает что вы присваиваете значение параметра самому себе, что приведет к проблемам при обращении к полю класса.*/
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`this` - константный указатель на текущий объект класса. В данном случае писать this не обязательно, так как компилятор сам подставит его. Есть случай когда идентификатор параметра и члена класса одинаковы:

```
class Class
{
public:
    int field;

    Class(int field)
    {       
        field = field; 
    }
    
    void setNumber(int number) { field = number; };
} obj;
```

Здесь происходит самоприсваивание, т.к параметр перекрывает видимость члена класса. 2 способа это предовратить: `Class::field` или `this->field`.

`this` передается как невидимый параметр в методы класса. При вызове `obj.setNumber(4);` C++ понимает, что функция `setNumber()` работает с объектом `obj`, а `field` — это фактически `obj.field`. Рассмотрим детально, как это всё работает.

Возьмем, к примеру, следующую строку:

```
obj.setNumber(4);
```

Хотя на первый взгляд кажется, что у нас здесь только один аргумент, но на самом деле у нас их два! Во время компиляции строка `obj.setNumber(4);` конвертируется компилятором в следующее:

```
setNumber(&obj, 4);
```

Теперь это всего лишь стандартный вызов функции, а объект `obj` (который ранее был отдельным объектом и находился перед точкой) теперь передается по адресу в качестве аргумента функции.

Но это только половина дела. Поскольку в вызове функции теперь есть два аргумента, то и метод нужно изменить соответствующим образом (чтобы он принимал два аргумента). Следовательно, следующий метод:

```
void setNumber(int number) { field = number; }
```

Конвертируется компилятором в:

```
void setNumber(Class* const this, int number) { this->field = number; }
```

Также `this` зачастую возвращают операторы класса, чтобы можно было делать цепочки: `obj = obj1 = obj2;`

Comment: *Также this зачастую возвращают операторы* - зачастую возвращают `*this`...